# Should I reply to emails for grad school that appear to be non specific?

Tags: graduate-admissions, email

I am getting emails from schools about their grad school programs, most likely due to attending a grad school fair and clicking certain check-boxes after taking my Biology GRE.

I have not taken my regular GRE exams and will not get to take them until the spring of 2016, when there deadlines for the programs they are "advertising" are December.

Should I respond to these replies in anyway?

Comment: Meta is for questions about using the main site (e.g. "Is this question too narrow for the main site?") - a completely different subject matter- not for answers to questions that are about the same subject matter as the main site, but too narrow or broad. I am migrating this back to main.

Comment: There is one situation in which you might want to respond.  If there are a few basic questions (e.g. regarding support) that you would like to have an answer to for a large variety of institutions, then you could send the same paragraph to each institution that contacts you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had taken an ETS-driven exam,already, and let ETS give your email address to the universities... These kind of emails would often be received by many graduate applicants, all over the world...

Hence, you should not assume that these emails are just for you, specifically based on your situation. There are just a bunch of advertisements to catch your attention for potential apply into them.

Furthermore, with due attention to the intrinsic information-based characteristics of these emails, one could assert that there is no need to take any reply into account.